# what is the shortcut key to close the script output window in SQL developer(v4.1)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

we can use ALT + Page up/Down to navigate between worksheet and script output windows but I'm unable to find any shortcut key to close it.

Comment: Tools - preferences - shortcut keys - try to find your answer there...

Comment: @Tatiana i posted this question after search in preferences. I couldn't find any shortcut key for this

Comment: We can press ALT+ page down, it will come in query result window then press F8+ end key, it will minimize the query result window but when i press ALT + page UP key now it is not coming back in worksheet.

Comment: as some workaround: you can switch from current tab and come back to it with `Ctrl + Tab` and focus will be in the editor

Comment: @agent5566 Thanks, it solved my problem. How can I transfer the bounty to you?

Comment: @VickyArora  I've posted the answer so you can accept it with bounty ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first and main thing to learn is the magic-keyboard-sequence to take focus off the editor or grid and onto the splitter itself

Shift + ALT + F8

Then…

HOME to go full-screen output

END to go full-screen editor

UP/DOWN arrows to move the splitter

Click on the screen or hit ESC to get out of ‘move splitter mode.

Comment: Thanks Jeff for logging bug.

Comment: any news about that? Five years later I still don't know how to hide script output window.

Comment: Why'd you wait 5 years to ask @frenkyb ?? https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2019/06/hide-or-full-screen-query-results/

Answer (score 3):

As some workaround: you can switch from current tab and come back to it with Ctrl + Tab and focus will be in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

In windows, F8+HOME and F8+END